# Base64.encode string is not working in python, type Error:memory view:a byte like object is required

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to get live streaming in python i have found error on this line,I have tried all possible solution on internet and stack overflow but didn't work out on my code,I am using Anaconda Prompt-Python 3.6.4

```
auth_encoded = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, password))[:-1]
```

i have also tried

- auth_encoded=base64.b64encode(base64.b64decode('%s:%s' % (user,
  password)))
- auth_encoded=base64.b64encode(bytes('%s:%s' % (user, password)))
- auth_s = urllib.parse.unquote(('%s:%s' % (user, password)))
     auth_bytes = auth_s.encode()
     encoded_bytes = base64.encodestring(auth_bytes)

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcswg.png)

Comment: Please reformat your code. A list is not great for code since it has format limitations.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code or error messages, post the text directly here on SO.